# DHCP server issues

Tags: dhcp

I have server running DHCP as well as DNS.
The network series is 10.241.0.1 to 10.241.0.105

Questions:

Q: if I want the DHCP server to offer IP addresses in the network of 10.241.1.1, is it possible or do I need to put the DHCP server in the network series of 1.

Q: When trying to PXE boot a client PC, it says no dhcp proxies were offered.  How do I resolve that ?

Q: While entering the scope in the DHCP server, the DHCPp server says the IPs are overlapped or are invalid IP addresses, any solutions?

Answer (score -1):

The problem of mine was never answered by anyone which motivated me to find the solution by myself.

Q: if i want the dhcp server to offer ip address in the network of 10.241.1.1 is it possible or i need to take the dhcp server in the network series of 1.
If there are 2 network, 10.241.0.1/24 and 10.241.1.1/24, and you want the DHCP server (which is belong to network 10.241.0.1/24 ) to provide DHCP service to clients on network 10.241.1.1/24. You may configure a DHCP relay agent on network 10.241.1.1/24, in order to forwarder DHCP messages between clients (which are on network 10.241.1.1/24) and DHCP server. Detailed information about how to configure DHCP relay agent you may reference the link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469685.aspx

Q: sometimes there is a problem in wds , the client pc says no dhcp proxies were offered, how do i resolve that ?
On the client which says no DHCP proxies were offered, open CMD, type “ipconfig /all” and hit Enter, check to see if it obtains the correct parameters. If not, type “ipconfig /release“ and “ipconfig /renew” to renew IP address.

Q:While entering the scope in the dhcp server, the dhcp server says the IP is overlapped or invalid ip address, any solutions ?
On a DHCP server, you can create only on scope for a subnet. If you have created a scope from 10.241.0.1 to 10.241.0.105, with subnet mask 255.255.255.0, then a scope with network ID 10.241.0.0 can’t be created. You may use Exclusions to resolve this problem. If the problem still exit, please provide the scope and relate parameters you want to add, and the exiting scope you have already added on the DHCP server.

Q: i have multiple operating systems to deploys via network, so how is that possible , should i create a new image group or can i add the images in the same images and will it ask during the startup ? i tried by adding the other os to the group , the first os gets booted and installed but when i select the second operating system says, wdsclient error, no dhcp offered , , , , and so.
You must have a working DHCP server with an active scope on the network because Windows Deployment Services uses PXE, which relies on DHCP for IP addressing. Make sure that your DHCP implement is working and let us resolve the above 3 problems first. Besides, you may reference the link for detailed information about Windows Deployment Services Getting Started Guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771670(v=WS.10).aspx